# Moveit! Using solve type speed instead of distance

Tags: ros, python, moveit, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I switched to using trac_ik for my kinematics plugin and set the solve type to distance. Here's my kinematics.yaml

```
manipulator:
  kinematics_solver: trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin
  solve_type: Distance
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.002
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.1
  kinematics_solver_attempts: 300
```

However, when I launch MoveIt I get the following messages:

```
[ INFO] [1498738699.604294668]: Looking in private handle: /move_group_commander_wrappers_1498738699102337314 for param name: manipulator/solve_type
[ INFO] [1498738699.605287670]: Using solve type Speed
```

Am I setting the solve type incorrectly for use in MoveIt?

---

EDIT: I added

```
 <group ns="move_group">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find PACKAGE_NAME)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
  </group>
```

to the start of my move_group.launch file. MoveIt! now displays the correct solve type on launch, but when I run code to move my robot, the terminal running my code still says its using solve type Speed.

```
[ INFO] [1498748362.955713863]: Looking in private handle: /move_group_commander_wrappers_1498748362452794445 for param name: manipulator/position_only_ik
[ INFO] [1498748362.960244821]: Looking in private handle: /move_group_commander_wrappers_1498748362452794445 for param name: manipulator/solve_type
[ INFO] [1498748362.961557738]: Using solve type Speed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265135/moveit!-using-solve-type-speed-instead-of-distance/) by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24 on 2017-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in where parameters are expected to be by MoveIt and the plugins.
Have a look at this issue for details and a workaround:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/629#issuecomment-282573234

A proper fix for upstream MoveIt would be highly appreciated! :)

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on 2017-06-29**:
I edited my question, do I need to change some other files to get this to work with my code?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's slightly inconvenient, but IK plugins tend to search for their parameters in the namespace of the process (ie: node) that is hosting them. In the case of MoveIt Commander, that would be `move_group_commander_wrappers_1498738699102337314`.

But simply putting it in that namespace won't do: you probably have *three* instances of `trac_ik` hosted:

1. in `move_group` (this is MoveIt 'proper')
2. in `rviz` (for the MoveIt RViz plugin)
3. in `moveit_commander`

I'm not sure (as I wasn't around when this was designed) but I think that is because of efficiency reasons (ie: avoid having to call an IK solver over a ROS service, which adds overhead to every call). But to get consistent behaviour, it'd be important to make sure all instances get the same parameters.

See [traclabs/trac_ik#25](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/issues/25) for a related issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on 2017-06-29**:
I edited my question, do I need to change some other files to get this to work with my code?